# How do I configure httpd.conf file in a dedicated server

Tags: apache-2.2, php, dedicated-server

I recently hired a dedicated server with WHM/Cpanel Centos 64 bit. I have done setup for domains and it is ready to go live. but I need to do some advance config with Apache and php so how do I do that??

Comment: How long is a piece of string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have access to the main apache config dir, then you have to use .htaccess files.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: I do have all access its dedicated one. but using SSH i need to configure. but I am not familiar with SSH. is there any GUI version available?? I dont know whether .htaccess is enabled in config file...

Comment: If you can modify the main config of apache, then in Centos you should edit /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.
I used once cpanel, if i remember well there'd be a menu to configure ssh access